# MAAS "Failed deployment" on HP proliant DL380 G9

Tags: 16.04, boot, uefi, hp, maas

I'm trying to deploy Ubuntu 16.04 to "HP proliant DL380 G9", after many trials..
I got that every time I start commission and/or deploy 
the machine insanely **toggles** the boot mode from **UEFI** to **legacy boot**

commission starts "UEFI", Deploy start "legacy boot" and vise versa.

if I manually reset the machine and force commission/deployment PXE boot to be the same "UEFI", everything goes fine.

Not sure if it may be a server hardware issue or MAAS issue. 
where to find the power-on or PXE boot command from logs ?

the normal run without my intervention (commission "legacy boot" and deployment "UEFI") returns the Failed deployment and in the log it can't install the grub loader.

Any help?

related log:

```
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.4.0.98.103) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-98 (4.4.0-98.121) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.98.103) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.4.0.98.103) ...
Setting up os-prober (1.70ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up thermald (1.5-2ubuntu4) ...
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14) ...

Creating config file /etc/default/grub with new version
Generating grub configuration file ...
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
done
Setting up grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.7) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 8 GiB (8589930496 bytes)
no label, UUID=61a9331e-57a4-48d1-9628-d8532c18d4e6
Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['sh', '-c', 'exec "$0" "$@" 2>&1', 'install-grub', '/tmp/tmpok83tdgp/target', '/dev/sdb']
Exit code: 1
Reason: -
Stdout: + pkg=grub-pc
        + shift
        + dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
        Replacing config file /etc/default/grub with new version
        Generating grub configuration file ...
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
        done
        + update-grub
        Generating grub configuration file ...
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
        done
        + grub-install /dev/sdb
        Installing for i386-pc platform.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
        grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
        grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for RAID and LVM install.
        + exit
        failed to install grub!

Stderr: ''
curtin: Installation failed with exception: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['curtin', 'curthooks']
Exit code: 3
Reason: -
Stdout: Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
        Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3212 B]
        Fetched 9791 kB in 24s (400 kB/s)
        Reading package lists...
        Reading package lists...
        Building dependency tree...
        Reading state information...
        The following additional packages will be installed:
          crda grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common iw
          libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 linux-firmware linux-headers-4.4.0-98
          linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-headers-generic
          linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
          linux-image-generic os-prober thermald wireless-regdb
        Suggested packages:
          multiboot-doc grub-emu xorriso desktop-base fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0
          | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
        The following NEW packages will be installed:
          crda grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common iw
          libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 linux-firmware linux-generic
          linux-headers-4.4.0-98 linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-headers-generic
          linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
          linux-image-generic os-prober thermald wireless-regdb
        0 upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
        Need to get 117 MB of archives.
        After this operation, 519 MB of additional disk space will be used.
        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 grub-common amd64 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14 [1705 kB]
        Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 thermald amd64 1.5-2ubuntu4 [187 kB]
        Preconfiguring packages ...
        Fetched 117 MB in 21s (5466 kB/s)
        E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)
        Selecting previously unselected package grub-common.
        (Reading database ... 25509 files and directories currently installed.)

        Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic.
        Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic_4.4.0-98.121_amd64.deb ...
        Done.
        Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
        Unpacking thermald (1.5-2ubuntu4) ...
        Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
        Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
        Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
        Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
        Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
        Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
        Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14) ...
        update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
        Running in chroot, ignoring request.
        invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
        Setting up grub2-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14) ...
        Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14) ...
        Setting up libnl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
        Setting up libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
        Setting up wireless-regdb (2015.07.20-1ubuntu1) ...
        Setting up iw (3.17-1) ...
        Setting up crda (3.13-1) ...
        Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.13) ...
        Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
        Running depmod.
        update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
        Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
        run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
        W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
        run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
        run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
        W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
        run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        Setting up linux-image-generic (4.4.0.98.103) ...
        Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-98 (4.4.0-98.121) ...
        Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
        Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.98.103) ...
        Setting up linux-generic (4.4.0.98.103) ...
        Setting up os-prober (1.70ubuntu3.3) ...
        Setting up thermald (1.5-2ubuntu4) ...
        Running in chroot, ignoring request.
        invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
        Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14) ...

        Creating config file /etc/default/grub with new version
        Generating grub configuration file ...
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
        Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
        Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
          /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
          WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
        done
        Setting up grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.7) ...
        Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
        Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
        Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
        Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
        Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 8 GiB (8589930496 bytes)
        no label, UUID=61a9331e-57a4-48d1-9628-d8532c18d4e6
        Unexpected error while running command.
        Command: ['sh', '-c', 'exec "$0" "$@" 2>&1', 'install-grub', '/tmp/tmpok83tdgp/target', '/dev/sdb']
        Exit code: 1
        Reason: -
        Stdout: + pkg=grub-pc
                + shift
                + dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
                Replacing config file /etc/default/grub with new version
                Generating grub configuration file ...
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
                Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                done
                + update-grub
                Generating grub configuration file ...
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
                Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                done
                + grub-install /dev/sdb
                Installing for i386-pc platform.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
                  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
                grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
                grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for RAID and LVM install.
                + exit
                failed to install grub!

        Stderr: ''

Stderr: ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the iLO 4 firmware v2.55 ...  downgrading to version iLO 4 firmware v2.54 solved the issue,

Now every time I commission/deploy now it goes to what specified in the BIOS setting.