# Grub problem deploying with MAAS

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, maas, bios

I'm working with MAAS trying to deploy Ubuntu 16.04 on my servers, actually it is working but not as I would like, I mean it deploys well but I have errors in my logs and Grub does not get installed :

```
Setting up os-prober (1.70ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up thermald (1.5-2ubuntu4) ...
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18) ...

Creating config file /etc/default/grub with new version
Generating grub configuration file ...
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
```

I have a lot of these errors in my logs...

In my curtin file I asked for Grub to be installed on both of my disks (LVM) but it does not install it actually, I have to run it by myself once server is up.

Moreover my `/boot` is almost empty, I'm not having `init*`, `vmlinuz*` `config*` files. So I don't even know how my server is booting.
I think I'm missing something big in my config since I'm new with MAAS.

Here is my storage config :

```
storage:
  version: 1
  config:
  - id: sdb
    type: disk
    ptable: msdos
    path: /dev/sdb
    name: main_disk
    wipe: superblock-recursive
    grub_device: true
  - id: sdc
    type: disk
    ptable: msdos
    path: /dev/sdc
    wipe: superblock-recursive
    grub_device: true
  - id: sdb1
    type: partition
    number: 1
    size: 2GB
    device: sdb
    flag: boot
    wipe: superblock-recursive
  - id: sdc1
    type: partition
    number: 1
    size: 2GB
    device: sdc
    flag: boot
    wipe: superblock-recursive
  - id: md0
    type: raid
    name: md0
    raidlevel: 1
    devices:
    - sdb1
    - sdc1
    ptable: msdos
  - id: md0_format
    fstype: ext4
    type: format
    volume: md0
  - id: mount-md0_format
    device: md0_format
    path: /boot
    type: mount
  - id: sdb2
    type: partition
    size: 221GB
    device: sdb
    wipe: superblock-recursive
  - id: sdc2
    type: partition
    size: 221GB
    device: sdc
    wipe: superblock-recursive
  - id: md1
    type: raid
    name: md1
    raidlevel: 1
    devices:
    - sdb2
    - sdc2
    ptable: msdos
  - id: volgroup1
    name: vg00
    type: lvm_volgroup
    devices:
    - md1
  - id: lvmpart1
    name: root
    #size: 924G
    type: lvm_partition
    volgroup: volgroup1
  - id: lv1_fs
    name: storage
    type: format
    fstype: ext4
    volume: lvmpart1
  - id: lv1_mount
    type: mount
    path: /
    device: lv1_fs
swap:
  filename: swap.img
  size: 0
grub:
  install_devices:
     - /dev/sdb1
     - /dev/sdc1
```

If I refer to this post : 
[MAAS "Failed deployment" on HP proliant DL380 G9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977349/maas-failed-deployment-on-hp-proliant-dl380-g9)
, it could come from the way MAAS commissions and deploys UEFI or Legacy.
How can I check that it is commissioning & deploying using Legacy or UEFI ? My BIOS settings specify Legacy.

I hope you can help me with that and I'm sorry for my english !

Thank you

Ludwig

Answer (score 1):

I was actually mounting /boot before / and it is the only problem here.

Just swap both in my config storage make my deployment ok, here is the end of my storage config now :

```
- id: lv1_mount
  type: mount
  path: /
  device: lv1_fs
- id: mount-md0_format
  device: md0_format
  path: /boot 
  type: mount
```

Now my /boot contains all the files it should.